# How to know a string contains only particular words

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

How do I check if the string contains only words in an array?

I could return `true` if the string contains any word in the array using `Contains()`

```
public bool ValidateString(string strCondition)
{
       List<string> words = new List<string>() { "true", "false", "&&", "||", " " };
       foreach (string word in words)
       {
            if(strCondition.Contains(word))
                return true;                
       }
       return false;
}
```

But how can I return `false` if the string that is send as parameter(`strCondition`) contains any word or alphabet or number or etc etc other than `true`, `false`, `&&`, `||`,  ? Is there any option in `Regex` or can some one come up with a good solution?

**EDIT**

The following should return true

```
true && false || false && false
true || false && false && false
```

And the below should return false since it contains a word/number/special characters other than `true`, `false`, `&&`, `||`,

```
true & false || false < false  
true >> false && false && false
true and false 123 false && false
true || false && false xyz false
```

Comment: so you want to check if all `words` are in `strCondition`?

Comment: So you don't want to look for _words_ but sub-strings?

Comment: Your code will already return `false` if none of the values in `words` is in `strCondition`

Comment: Which is your priority condition? Containing `true`, `false`, `&&`, `||` or not containing any of this? Your algo is correct, just write your priority condition first.

Comment: I am confused with this question. "true" and "false" is already a word.

Comment: Nice, that would make sense, upping the question.

Comment: Can it have more than one of those terms or a compound of them?  Can they be separated with 1 or more spaces?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. If not clear, please feel free to ask

Comment: @SarathAvanavu just like amura.cxg mentioned.... Your code already returns false if none the words is matched....

Comment: If the string is '`true % false`, it will return true since '`true` is both in string as well as array. But it should have returned false since `%` is not in array. Does it make sense? @Rusty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your code suffers from the [clbuttic problem](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/clbuttic.htm): it would return `true` for a string that has a word "untrue", because the code does not pay attention to word boundaries.

If you would like to check if no other words are contained, split the string, and check each item against the list of "approved" words:

```
var allApproved = strCondition.Split(' ').All(word => words.Contains(word));
```

This approach implies that words in `words` do not contain spaces.

Note that this is not the most efficient approach, although it would work fine for a small list. If the list is very long, switch to a `HashSet<string>` instead.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/jcHAXi)

Comment: I guess OP wants to know if there is a sub-string which is not in the list `words`. So `||||` is allowed but not `||-`.

Comment: Yes Tim. Exactly. I want to know whether a string that is not in `words` @Tim Schmelter

Comment: This is the exact solution that I was looking for. Great one. Simple and well explained with less number of lines of code. Plus one. Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(^(true|false|&&|\|\|)$)");

return regex.IsMatch(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer which seems to be what you originally asked. If i got it right you wanted to know if only sub-strings are in the text which are in the `List<string>`.

So "untrue" would return `false` because "un" is not in the list of allowed "words" (better sub-strings). But "truetrue" would be allowed.

Then have a look at this method which looks more cumbersome but it needs to check something different than the accepted answer:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "false", "true", "||", "&&", " " };

public bool ValidateString(string strCondition)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strCondition)) return true;
    int charIndex = 0;
    while (charIndex < strCondition.Length)
    {
        string wordFound = null;
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word.Length + charIndex > strCondition.Length) 
                continue;
            string substring = strCondition.Substring(charIndex, word.Length);
            if (word == substring)
            {
                wordFound = word;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (wordFound == null)
            return false;
        else if (charIndex + wordFound.Length == strCondition.Length)
            return true;
        else
            charIndex += wordFound.Length;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that i've re-ordered the list, the longest strings should come first since that's more efficient in the algorithm above.

Two examples to demonstrate what it does:

```
bool check = ValidateString("truefalse||truetrue"); // true
bool check = ValidateString("truefals||etruetrue"); // false
```

Comment: No `truetrue` is not allowed. `true && true` or `true || true` is valid. I appreciate the effort for your valuable answer. I will make sure to use your code whenever there is a requirement which requires to treat `truetrue` as a valid string. Thanks Tim and +1 from my side :)